# Association Rule - Non-Binary Items

Tags: machine-learning

I have studied association rules and know how to implement the algorithm on the classic basket of goods problem, such as:

```
Transaction ID   Potatoes  Eggs   Milk
A                   1       0       1
B                   0       1       1
```

In this problem each item has a binary identifier. 1 indicates the basket contains the good, 0 indicates it does not.

But what would be the best way to model a basket which can contain many of the same good? E.g., take the below, very unrealistic example.

```
Transaction ID   Potatoes  Eggs   Milk
A                   5       0       178
B                   0       35      7
```

Using binary indicators in this case would obviously be losing a lot of information and I am seeking a model which takes into account not only the presence of items in the basket, but also the frequency that the items occur.

What would be a suitable algorithm for this problem?

In my actual data there are over one hundred items and, based on the profile of a user's basket, I would like to calculate the probabilities of the customer consuming the other available items.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to use binary indicators *but constructing them in a more clever way*.

The idea is to set the indicator when an amount is more than the *central value*,  which means that it shall be significant. If everyone buys 3 breads on average, does it make sense to flag someone as a "bread-lover" for buying two or three?

Central value can a plain arithmetic mean, one with outliers removed, or the median.

Instead of:

```
binarize(x)  =   0    if x = 0
                 1    otherwise
```

you can use

```
binarize*(x) =   0    if x <= central(X)
                 1    otherwise
```

Answer (score -2):

I think if you really want to have probabilities is to encode your data in a probabilistic way. Bayesian or Markov networks might be a feasible way. Nevertheless without having a reasonable structure this will be computational extremely expansive. For three item types this, however, seems to be feasible

I would try to go for a Neural Network Autoencoder if you have many more item types. If there is some dependency in the data it will discover that.

For the above example you could use a network with three input, two hidden and three output neurons.

A little bit more fancy would be to use 3 fully connected layers with drop out in the middle layer.